# Why does VS Code sometimes underline words and give an option to "Execute command" what I hover the word?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Which features does this option to "Execute command" come from, and (ideally) how do I disable it?

This happens even if I launch VS Code with `--disable-extensions`, so I don't think it's related to an extension.

[image: "Execute command" Example]

Comment: there are build-in extensions, see the install directory, the line with this False Positive link matches one of the X Providers (true name of X I don't know), is this in a Markdown file? It is the footnote syntax in Markdown but is not recognized by the Markdown preview as a footnote. Looks like a bug to me. File an issue in the Markdown language plugin. AFAIK Markdown does not have syntax for commands and when clicked on the link nothing happens. It looks also like line of a Notebook line `[1]: foo bar`

Comment: Thanks, this is a good lead. When I switch from Markdown to Plain Text, this problem goes away. Also good point about the Notebook syntax, good chance it's related to that. I've filed an issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-markdown-tm-grammar/issues/78 Although I'm not 100% sure that's the right repo.

Comment: I think just create the issue in VSC repo, because it is probably in `markdown-basics` or `markdown-language-features` both build-in extenstions.